# Python: the While loop at the end keeps generating a new random card, how can I get it to generate once and stop?

Tags: python, loops, random, while-loop, pygame

The code below is skeletal, it is supposed to be the beginning of a card game.  I generated a random hand (1 card for now) but I can't seem to get it to only generate the first hand once.  The while loop repeats and constantly generates a new random card for the first hand.

edit: it no repeatedly generates a random card but now it crashes

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import*

WINWIDTH = 1200
WINHEIGHT = 800
CARDTHUMBWIDTH = 50
CARDTHUMBHEIGHT = 80
FPS = 30
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINWIDTH,WINHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('NBA Card Game')
pygame.init()

playerHandPos = [(17, 635), (75, 635), (133, 635), (191, 635), (249, 635), (307, 635), (365, 635), (423, 635), (481, 635), (539, 635)]
lakersDeck = ['Lakers_01.png', 'Lakers_02.png', 'Lakers_03.png', 'Lakers_04.png', 'Lakers_05.png', 'Lakers_06.png', 'Lakers_07.png', 'Lakers_08.png', 'Lakers_09.png', 'Lakers_10.png']

turnCount = 0
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)
userTextPrompt = "20, 725"
playMat = pygame.image.load('playmat.png')
detailBox = pygame.image.load('detailBox.png')
DISPLAYSURF.blit(playMat, (0,0))

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

##def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
##    textobj = font.render(text, 1, (0,0,0))
##    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
##    textrect.topleft = (x,y)
##    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

def getFirstHand():
    random.shuffle(lakersDeck)
    firstHand = [lakersDeck[0], lakersDeck[1], lakersDeck[2], lakersDeck[3]]
    return firstHand

def displayHand():
    cardThumb = pygame.image.load(playerHand[0])
    cardThumb = pygame.transform.scale(cardThumb, (50,80))
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(cardThumb, playerHandPos[0])
    pygame.display.update()

def playerTurn():
    placedBench = False
    while placedBench == False:
        drawText("Choose a card for your bench.", font, DISPLAYSURF, 20, 725)
        pygame.display.update()    

def cardLakers_01():
    offense = 10
    return offense

while True:
    playerHand = []
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    print(mouse)
    if turnCount == 0:
        getFirstHand()
        playerHand = getFirstHand()
        turnCount += 1

    displayHand()
    playerTurn()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            terminate()
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                terminate()
        if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            if 67 > mouse[0] > 17 and 710 > mouse[1] > 635:
                cardDashImage = pygame.image.load('Lakers_01.png')
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(cardDashImage, (925, 200))
                pygame.display.update()
            else:
                detailBox = pygame.image.load('detailBox.png')
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(detailBox, (900,0))
                pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: `FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()`: then you're using `FPSCLOCK` which doesnt call the function BTW.

Comment: of course, since your getFirstHand routine is called everytime you display. The random is here. You should do it once, and store the result instead.

Comment: In your while loop, you have this code : if turnCount == 0:  getFirstHand(), but you are not using the value that is being returned by the getFirstHand() function.

Comment: If you're experiencing a crash, including the traceback makes it easier for us to help you. Also, it's better to load your resources once, at the beginning and then copy them to the appropriate surface/sprite.

Answer (score 1):

You don't break from the while loop so it will keep cycling through the loop. So when your code runs, it 'turnCount' gets reset back to 0 each time it has changed. You want to move the turnCount declaration outside of the while loop so that turnCount is only equal to 0 at the start of the program

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Although it's crashing for another reason with no error message, but it's only my 3rd week learning Python so I'll have to keep troubleshooting until I get better.

Comment: Yes, everyone has to start somewhere, my first language was Python. If you have an error message, edit your post and I'll help if I can :) also if my solution worked please give my answer an upvote

Comment: I upvoted but since my reputation is so low it says that it is recorded but not displayed publicly :(.. I made the update to my post, all I did was move the variable handCount near the top of my code with the other variables.  Thanks again!

Comment: You return playerHand from GetFirstHand() but you don't allow it to be stored where you call it. So when you call the function you need to have a place to take the return.  `variable = GetFirstHand()`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I assigned a variable for the return for getFirstHand() and it's still crashing not sure why, made another edit to my post

Comment: Do you get any error messages? If so what are they? and do you know how far through the program gets through the code